# Problem resizing div in Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, resize, height

**EDIT**: What happens can be seen in this page when the height resolution is lower than the entire page (eg.: 1024x768): http://www.depositosalto.com.br/pagamentos.php

I trying to resize a div with the content of page with javascript to always the page fit in the whole screen when it is smaller.

I'm using the following javascript and it works in other navigators(Firefox, Opera). In Chrome it resizes the div too, but unlike the others, it don't pushs the footer div which is just below the content div.

Is there any way around it in chrome?

```
function defineContentHeight(height){       
  var screenHeight = window.innerHeight;                
  if (screenHeight > (height + 220)){
    height = screenHeight - 220;                
    document.getElementById("content").style.height = height + "px";        
  }
  else{                     
    document.getElementById("content").style.height = height + "px";        
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The content inside the "conteudo" div is floating, so the height isn't calculated; you can do one of two things:

Add the "overflow:auto" style to the "conteudo" div, which is generally safe, or

Add a div with a style of "clear:both" to the very bottom of the "conteudo" div

For what it's worth, I'm not seeing your bug in Chrome 11, but my guess is that one of those might fix it.

Comment: Yes, no more bugs. I think that the problem I described was related to other. I was having a problem with encoding (the page don' display in IE properly and this bug in Chrome), but after fixed the encoding, the IE problem disappeared, and by the way, the problem with Chrome followed the same path. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: try css `resize: both`